# how to create my own validation in magento

Tags: javascript, validation, magento

I am trying to customise the email validation following this [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/), but my magento is not picking up my new js files.

I have created a new `/public_html/js/newValidation.js` file:

```
Validation.add('validate-email', 'Please enter a valid gmail address. For example johndoe@gmail.com.', function(v) {
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]*@gmail\.com)$/i.test(v)
})
```

then I edit the  `/public_html/app/design/frontend/<theme>/default/layout/local.xml` file:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        ...
        <reference name="head">
            ...
            <action method="addJs"><script>newValidation.js</script></action>
            ...
```

But newValidation.js is not loading to the `http://<domain>/customer/account/create` page

NOTE: I also tried adding the js into `/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml` with same result

Any idea why my js is not loading?

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/ have a look

Comment: @urfusion my code is based on that example

Answer (score 0):

You should put local.xml file at {package}/{theme}/layout. Probably you use not default theme and file local.xml already exists in your custom theme and it override local.xml from default theme.
Just check what theme and package you use at 
system->configuration->general->design